# Why does React.js sometimes not let me use `debugger`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging

Sometimes I can put `debugger;` statements in my React components and it works, and sometimes it doesn't.  For instance, I am calling my react component like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    debugger;
    var nav = React.createElement(SubLocationSelector, {instanceID: @Model.InstanceID, locationID: @Model.LocationID, OnSublocationSelected: function(id, fullPath) {alert("ID: " + id + "; FullPath: " + fullPath);}}, null);
    ReactDOM.render(nav, document.getElementById("drill-down-nav"));
</script>
```

and its debugger point gets hit.  However inside the React component:

```
class SubLocationSelector extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        debugger;
        super(props);
        this.model = new SubLocationSelectorViewModel();
        this.model.loadSubLocations(this.props.locationID);
    }
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        debugger;
        if(nextProps.locationID != this.props.locationID){
            this.model.loadSubLocations(nextProps.locationID)
        }
    }
    render() {
        debugger;
        return (
            <ViewModelBinder model={this.model}>
                <SublocationSelectorDisplay model={this.model} 
                                            OnSublocationSelected={this.props.OnSublocationSelected} />
            </ViewModelBinder>
        )
    }
}
```

none of these debugger points get hit if I run the code in Chrome with devtools open.  I haven't yet isolated why some of my react components work with debugger and some don't, but I'm pretty confident it has to do with React.

Furthermore: is there a way to fix this behavior?

EDIT:

It's been suggested that this may be a culprit of a babel plugin such as remove-debugger.  Here are the babel plugins listed by `npm ls`:

[image: npm ls gets me this]

I don't have a `.babelrc` file or a `package.json`.

Searching for `remove-debugger` in my entire solution gets no results.

EDIT2:

There are two different package.jsons that might be used by babel:

```
{
  "_args": [
    [
      {
        "raw": "babel-runtime@^6.20.0",
        "scope": null,
        "escapedName": "babel-runtime",
        "name": "babel-runtime",
        "rawSpec": "^6.20.0",
        "spec": ">=6.20.0 <7.0.0",
        "type": "range"
      },
      "C:\\develop\\trakref\\node_modules\\babel-traverse"
    ]
  ],
  "_from": "babel-runtime@>=6.20.0 <7.0.0",
  "_id": "babel-runtime@6.20.0",
  "_inCache": true,
  "_location": "/babel-runtime",
  "_nodeVersion": "6.9.0",
  "_npmOperationalInternal": {
    "host": "packages-12-west.internal.npmjs.com",
    "tmp": "tmp/babel-runtime-6.20.0.tgz_1481239547266_0.8724558432586491"
  },
  "_npmUser": {
    "name": "hzoo",
    "email": "hi@henryzoo.com"
  },
  "_npmVersion": "3.10.8",
  "_phantomChildren": {},
  "_requested": {
    "raw": "babel-runtime@^6.20.0",
    "scope": null,
    "escapedName": "babel-runtime",
    "name": "babel-runtime",
    "rawSpec": "^6.20.0",
    "spec": ">=6.20.0 <7.0.0",
    "type": "range"
  },
  "_requiredBy": [
    "/babel-messages",
    "/babel-traverse",
    "/babel-types"
  ],
  "_resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/babel-runtime/-/babel-runtime-6.20.0.tgz",
  "_shasum": "87300bdcf4cd770f09bf0048c64204e17806d16f",
  "_shrinkwrap": null,
  "_spec": "babel-runtime@^6.20.0",
  "_where": "C:\\develop\\trakref\\node_modules\\babel-traverse",
  "author": {
    "name": "Sebastian McKenzie",
    "email": "sebmck@gmail.com"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.10.0"
  },
  "description": "babel selfContained runtime",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-helpers": "^6.6.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.9.0"
  },
  "directories": {},
  "dist": {
    "shasum": "87300bdcf4cd770f09bf0048c64204e17806d16f",
    "tarball": "https://registry.npmjs.org/babel-runtime/-/babel-runtime-6.20.0.tgz"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "maintainers": [
    {
      "name": "amasad",
      "email": "amjad.masad@gmail.com"
    },
    {
      "name": "hzoo",
      "email": "hi@henryzoo.com"
    },
    {
      "name": "jmm",
      "email": "npm-public@jessemccarthy.net"
    },
    {
      "name": "loganfsmyth",
      "email": "loganfsmyth@gmail.com"
    },
    {
      "name": "sebmck",
      "email": "sebmck@gmail.com"
    }
  ],
  "name": "babel-runtime",
  "optionalDependencies": {},
  "readme": "ERROR: No README data found!",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages/babel-runtime"
  },
  "scripts": {},
  "version": "6.20.0"
}
```

and this one:

```
{
  "_args": [
    [
      {
        "raw": "core-js@^2.4.0",
        "scope": null,
        "escapedName": "core-js",
        "name": "core-js",
        "rawSpec": "^2.4.0",
        "spec": ">=2.4.0 <3.0.0",
        "type": "range"
      },
      "C:\\develop\\trakref\\node_modules\\babel-runtime"
    ]
  ],
  "_from": "core-js@>=2.4.0 <3.0.0",
  "_id": "core-js@2.4.1",
  "_inCache": true,
  "_location": "/babel-runtime/core-js",
  "_nodeVersion": "6.2.2",
  "_npmOperationalInternal": {
    "host": "packages-16-east.internal.npmjs.com",
    "tmp": "tmp/core-js-2.4.1.tgz_1468791807265_0.5941079026088119"
  },
  "_npmUser": {
    "name": "zloirock",
    "email": "zloirock@zloirock.ru"
  },
  "_npmVersion": "3.9.5",
  "_phantomChildren": {},
  "_requested": {
    "raw": "core-js@^2.4.0",
    "scope": null,
    "escapedName": "core-js",
    "name": "core-js",
    "rawSpec": "^2.4.0",
    "spec": ">=2.4.0 <3.0.0",
    "type": "range"
  },
  "_requiredBy": [
    "/babel-runtime"
  ],
  "_resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/core-js/-/core-js-2.4.1.tgz",
  "_shasum": "4de911e667b0eae9124e34254b53aea6fc618d3e",
  "_shrinkwrap": null,
  "_spec": "core-js@^2.4.0",
  "_where": "C:\\develop\\trakref\\node_modules\\babel-runtime",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/issues"
  },
  "dependencies": {},
  "description": "Standard library",
  "devDependencies": {
    "LiveScript": "1.3.x",
    "es-observable-tests": "0.2.x",
    "eslint": "3.1.x",
    "grunt": "1.0.x",
    "grunt-cli": "1.2.x",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "1.0.x",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "1.0.x",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "1.0.x",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "1.0.x",
    "grunt-karma": "2.0.x",
    "grunt-livescript": "0.6.x",
    "karma": "1.1.x",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "1.0.x",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "1.0.x",
    "karma-ie-launcher": "1.0.x",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "1.0.x",
    "karma-qunit": "1.1.x",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "2.1.x",
    "promises-aplus-tests": "2.1.x",
    "qunitjs": "2.0.x",
    "temp": "0.8.x",
    "webpack": "1.13.x"
  },
  "directories": {},
  "dist": {
    "shasum": "4de911e667b0eae9124e34254b53aea6fc618d3e",
    "tarball": "https://registry.npmjs.org/core-js/-/core-js-2.4.1.tgz"
  },
  "gitHead": "5e106f64c726edf2849f0babc9096ce6664b7368",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/zloirock/core-js#readme",
  "keywords": [
    "ES3",
    "ECMAScript 3",
    "ES5",
    "ECMAScript 5",
    "ES6",
    "ES2015",
    "ECMAScript 6",
    "ECMAScript 2015",
    "ES7",
    "ES2016",
    "ECMAScript 7",
    "ECMAScript 2016",
    "Harmony",
    "Strawman",
    "Map",
    "Set",
    "WeakMap",
    "WeakSet",
    "Promise",
    "Symbol",
    "TypedArray",
    "setImmediate",
    "Dict",
    "polyfill",
    "shim"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "main": "index.js",
  "maintainers": [
    {
      "name": "zloirock",
      "email": "zloirock@zloirock.ru"
    }
  ],
  "name": "core-js",
  "optionalDependencies": {},
  "readme": "ERROR: No README data found!",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/zloirock/core-js.git"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "grunt": "grunt",
    "lint": "eslint es5 es6 es7 stage web core fn modules",
    "observables-tests": "node tests/observables/adapter && node tests/observables/adapter-library",
    "promises-tests": "promises-aplus-tests tests/promises-aplus/adapter",
    "test": "npm run lint && npm run grunt livescript client karma:default && npm run grunt library karma:library && npm run promises-tests && npm run observables-tests && lsc tests/commonjs"
  },
  "version": "2.4.1"
}
```

Comment: and if you have a `console.log` below the debugger its showing up?

Comment: Probably because you have a webpack/babel transform that is removing console and/or debugging statements

Comment: @finalfreq yes, `console.log` shows up

Comment: @MatthewHerbst you're probably right, because we are using babel, and I can see that that's a transform it can do.  Unfortunately, so far I have been unable to find where in my solution that it's setting `remove-debugger` (assuming that's what is causing this).

Comment: Maybe you should update the question with your babel and/or webpack configs? :)

Comment: @MatthewHerbst I've updated with more info; let me know if there's other places I should be looking for babel plugins besides these.

Comment: @MatthewHerbst the only webpack.configs and .babelrc files I can find are not used by my part of the project and have hardly anything in them anyways; no reference to debug.

Comment: Where are your babel settings if you don't have a `.babelrc` or a `package.json`?

Comment: `debugger` => `eval('debugger')` will work? hope babel not transform `eval`

Comment: @JiangYD I get `JSX Parser: unexpected token =>` when trying that.

Comment: @levininja sorry that I not said it clearly. I mean replace `debugger` with `eval('debugger')`

Comment: @JiangYD that does work!  It hits the debugger line in the console.  If you want to make that an answer to the question I can accept it.  (edited this comment to be more accurate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace `debugger` with `eval('debugger')`, `babel` will not transform the string value.